# comparing two dates at midnight in vb never match

Tags: vb.net

I have two dates, both at midnight
e.g. 06/06/2014 and 12/29/2014
Both dates are exactly midnight (at least they should be), they are in datetime format and show no time section
I am using adddays to add 1 day each time in a loop until the
1st date = 2nd date
Problem is that even though on debug the dates eventually look equal, they are never equal and the loop continues.
I have also compared them in an if statement and they are not equal but they look the same.
Any help most welcome.

Comment: Show us your code please.

Comment: `at least they should be` may be the fly in the ointment.  If course all sorts of this may go wrong if they are not actual `DateTime` types, but strings.

Comment: are there any milliseconds in the datetime that make them different?

Comment: try to compare (1st date).Date=2nd.Date to ensure that only comparing the date part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to compare two DateTime instances, but ignore their time component, you should use the `DateTime.Date` property, e.g:

```
if (date1.Date = date2.Date) then
  ...
```